# No output from Plotly express choropleth

Tags: python, plot, plotly, geojson, choropleth

I am unable to get a plot of choropleth map from the given code. I have tried it on Google colab and VS Code on my laptop but its not showing any output.....

I have also tried double clicking but that's not working...

```
import json
import pandas as pd
import plotly.express as px
import plotly.io as pio
pio.renderers.default = 'browser'

x = json.load(open("odisha_disticts.geojson","r"))


y = pd.read_csv("data.csv")
y.drop("Unnamed: 0",axis = 'columns',inplace=True)


fig = px.choropleth(
    y,
    locations="id",
    geojson=x,
    color="Females"
)
fig.update_geos(fitbounds="locations", visible=False)
fig.show()
```

[Output view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MptKI.png)

[The link to the required files are](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/10do9-weVkqci8MJIgYmF-fRbSC1aqzxt)

Thank You in advance.......

Comment: try `plt.show()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I do not see a column for Females or ID in the user data presented. That is the reason. I created a choropleth map from the presented geosjon data with sample data.

```
import json
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import plotly.express as px
import plotly.io as pio
#pio.renderers.default = 'browser'

x = json.load(open("./odisha_disticts.geojson","r"))

user_data = []
for i in range(len(x['features'])):
    d = x['features'][i]['properties']
    d['Females'] = np.random.randint(0,100,1)[0]
    user_data.append(d)
df = pd.DataFrame(user_data)

df.head()
    ID_2    NAME_2  Females
0   16084   Angul   19
1   16085   Baleshwar   45
2   16086   Baragarh    52
3   16087   Bhadrak     81
4   16088   Bolangir    49

fig = px.choropleth(
    df,
    locations="ID_2",
    featureidkey="properties.ID_2",
    geojson=x,
    color="Females"
)
fig.update_geos(fitbounds="locations", visible=False)
fig.show()
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Specify the feature_id from the geojson to use as reference.

```
fig = px.choropleth(
    y, geojson=x,
    featureidkey="properties.ID_2",
    locations="id",
    color="Females"
)
```